# Convert Custom Firefox Setup to Firefox Portable?

Tags: firefox, portable, thunderbird

I have a pretty awesome firefox set up and spent a lot of time getting it perfect. Is there any way that anyone knows about to convert the entire configuration to portable? Programs like MozBackup are great for backing up the complete set up, but you can't restore a Firefox profile to Firefox portable (maybe there is a workaround to fake it out? or possibly another method?)

In case anyone is interested here is the gist of the best add-ons I've found:

Autopager (scroll down google and other multi page results without clicking next)
Coral IE Tab (IE in firefox - in case a website 'insists' that you use IE)
Cyber search (search google straight from the address bar - VERY HELPFUL)
Download StatusBar (display progress of downloads in the bottom of ff - no annoying popups
FireFTP (erases need for an external FTP client - opens in a tab)
Gmail manager (if you use multiple gmail accounts)
Session Manager (saving multiple sessions of tabs - ff session recover)
Surf Canyon (pull relevant stuff out of the depths of search results - even from craigslist
Tab Mix Plus (ESSENTIAL - tab behavior customization - have multiple rows of tabs

I also have it set up so you can type 'g test' in the address bar and ff will pull up the google results for 'test'. Similarly have it set up for guitar tabs (tab), facebook (f), wikipedia (w), google maps from my house (gmhome), torrents (tor), ticketmaster (t), rotten tomatoes (rt), craiglist (c) plus about 20 other sites.

Comment: Also, is this possible with thunderbird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) has this functionality.